# Airflow UI: 404 Error Message when setting up connection with API

Tags: airflow

I want to connect my airflow instance with an API.

When testing the connection (from the connections page of airlfow), I get a '404:Not Found' error.

Here is what I entered in the connections page:

Connection Id = realty_mole_api

Connection Type = HTTP

Host = realty-mole-property-api.p.rapidapi.com

Schema = https

Extra = {"X-RapidAPI-Key": <my_api_key>}

---

The API URL is https://realty-mole-property-api.p.rapidapi.com

The headers from the API code snippet are:

```
headers: {
    'X-RapidAPI-Key': 'b2d2dc0109mshb34de57573fb58ap1f4781jsn24951b2d86a0',
    'X-RapidAPI-Host': 'realty-mole-property-api.p.rapidapi.com'
  }
```

I've tested the API endpoint in my IDE and it works fine.
Also, if it's helpful, I haven't loaded my DAG into Airflow yet.

Any one have any clue what the issue could be? I'm a beginner in all of this
Thank you